# jQuery function: toggle, id with alternating names

Tags: jquery, html

I'm kinda new to jQuery and I did get the toggle function to work as I needed, but I was wondering if there was a more general-specific approach to handling the target id's with it. I'll give you my code and an example of what I mean.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#toggler').click(function(){
        $('ul#toggled').toggle();
    });
});
```

Html:

```
<ul>
    <li><a id="toggler" class="g" onclick="toggle()">Specializations</a>
    <ul id="toggled">
        <li>[Spec 1]</li>
        <li>[Spec 2]</li>
        <li>[Spec 3]</li></ul></li>
    <li>Playing Styles</li>
    <li>Stats, Gems, Enchants</li>
    <li>Gear</li>
    <li><a id="toggler" onclick="toggle()">Professions</a>
            <ul id="toggled">
            <li>Primary</li>
            <li>Secondary</li></ul></li>
</ul>
```

I want the toggle function to work on the submenus by clicking the list item they're originating from. At the moment, this does give me what I want, but it also targets all the toggle functions in the menu at the same time. How can I use a general solution that will target the 'toggler' and immediately 'toggled' pairs? Would using variables in the names help, and if so how? Would putting it in an array be better? I'm not sure how to do this so any help is appreciated. Let me know if I need to give more information.

Comment: I don't know of a way to target classes with js. I know of this: document.getelementbyid. That makes me thing you can only use id's though so that's what I used. I'll look up how to you use classes and change my style accordingly. I know how to use classes and id's correctly between html and css.

Comment: Targeting classes in jQuery is as basic as targeting IDs. Instead of ` $('#toggler')` you'd use ` $('.toggler')` when then class is toggler.

Comment: I actually just figured that out. Thank you for telling me though. After researching, I also found that there's a 'document.getelementbyclass'. Go figure. I had to google it, but yea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the way that your DOM is structured above my, solution would be the following ->

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#toggler').click(function(){
    $(this).next('ul.toggled').toggle();
  });
});
```

`$(this)` refers to the element we clicked, `next()` is a jQuery selector & abstractor, and finally. We literally are saying, `"Toggle the next UL with an ID of #toggled"`

I believe what you want is specific portions of the list to open, and not all of the lists. Also, don't use ID's over and over, it's not good practice, change these to classes, now you're good.

***extras***

> Also, i don't know what the 'toggler()' function does onClick, but you should just remove that, as jQuery is handling the eventListener for the click method.

Comment: I thought that with js you're supposed to target elements like this document.getelementbyid. That's why I was using that id. If I'd known you could use a class, I would've. I do use classes and id's correctly otherwise. Thank you for your answer. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: in jQuery, we have many methods to traverse the DOM and make our selection. That's one of the larger purposes of the jQuery library, is DOM Traversal and Abstraction.

Comment: document.getElementById is just one method, but things getElementsByTagName for example, return a node list, rather then a reference to a particular DOM element.  So you would need to handle finding your elements and/or assigning the events a little differently, namely with a loop.  However jQuery can make this process much more efficient and cleaner, as exampled above.

Comment: I think I put the onclick there for extra reassurance. Not sure either. As I said in my post above. I'm new to jQuery. I'm trying to get the hang of it. Not doing so well. I'll keep reading and find a solution. Thank you for you help.